# Why does Android Eclipse constantly refresh external folders and take forver?

Tags: android, eclipse, performance, refresh

Just my a new Android phone and I've been tinkering with some basic apps. It's been driving my crazy that the Android plugin for Eclipse refreshes externals folders whenever I save ANYTHING. Normally I wouldn't mind but when it takes 10s to refresh I start to notice.

I already searched and other people have this problem, but there are no solutions.

If it matters, Eclipse 3.5 running on a 64bit jvm on Ubuntu 9.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try disabling "Build automatically" from the Project menu.

Comment: And then you should keep in mind for those generated files ;) You should delete them occasionally if you want your "Build automatically" off.

Comment: Solves my problem. Fingers crossed that Google fixes this one day.

Comment: @basszero your fingers will be just bones by then. Mine too.

Answer (score 25):

If you have references to external sources put them in a zip file:

YourProject->rightClick->Properties->Java Build Path->libraries->..., and then most notably android.jar, but other libs can be the culprit too. Expand it and and select Source attachment, and then (if it doesn't say 'None') press the 'Edit...'-button. If that points to a directory waht you should do is compress that source-directory into a zip file and make the source attachment point to that file.

Apparently eclipse/adt feels the need to refresh sources on the file-system. When they're in a zip-file it seems confident that they have not changed....

Answer (score 1):

First of all Eclipse has a cool feature called a Preferences menu which is located under the window menu located at the top of the screen. Inside there are all sorts settings for pretty much anything you could want to adjust, including the option to turn off Native file system hooks and polling (under General -> Workspace). This is the *actual* solution to your problem as disabling build automatically doesn't solve the external folders issue, as soon as you build your project it starts right back up with refreshing them. Just keep in mind that if you update your Android SDK at all you will probably need to right click on the root directory of your project and hit refresh after the update finishes.

Secondly, as far as Netbeans is concerned there are at least a half a dozen pages worth of forums posts and various methods for using the Android SDK with it that are also available through Google, I'd give it a look.

Answer (score 0):

I generally do the above step of turning off Automatic build and also try to have not more then 1 open project in my project list.

I myself am fed up of Eclipse from this. Importing a big android project 'ALWAYS' hangs my eclipse and i have to force close it and restart it.

P.S. I really wish google would create an Android plugin for Netbeans =(

Comment: I tend to blame the Android plug-in. I regularly work w/ dozens of projects spanning thousands of source files and Eclipse has no problem. One android project w/ ONE source file and minimal layout and Eclipse is toast.

Comment: If you can open "dozens of projects" and "thousands of source files" then you should probably not be having an issue with 1 source file. I can build the entire AOSP source tree in the background while I work in Eclipse, Photoshop, Illustrator and Flash Builder without any problem.