# How to avoid "Refreshing external Folders" in Android development in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am having this annoying problem which takes 10-20 seconds and sometimes more every time my android project is refreshed or rebuilt.

[image]

I searched for android forums and also in stackoverflow and but solutions does not make sense. Please give me the solution or link to it.

My android project depends on two external java libs and android libs. Tell me if you need more info.

---

Earlier I asked this question and it solved the problem by removing 'source attachment'. But I believe it is not a good solution because I need source to be attached with jar. It helps while debugging, code browsing. If source is not attached then, your breakpoint stops there and you can't go in readable source.

**Better Solution Needed.** Is there a launcher option? which disables when app launched. or build options?

---

Comment: For Better Solution see Governa's answer. It's what you're looking for. Consider checking it as best answer.

Comment: BTW, there is another option. Instead of waiting for completion of the process, one can switch to `Progress` tab and press `stop` button (with red rect). This terminates the refreshing process but next steps, such as launching, will run normally (instantly).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The reason for this is that you have attached source with your dependent jars. Just the remove the source from the class path. This how it can be done.

Right click on the project -> Select `Build Path` -> `Configure Build Path..` -> Select `Libraries`

[image]

Select the `Source attachment` and `Remove` button will highlight. Press `Remove` and `OK`.

I think that should fix your issue.

Comment: It solved my problem. Thanks a lot. I had given up and thought I will have to reinstall android SDK.  Cheer Havexz.

Comment: Earlier I asked this question and it solved the problem by removing 'source attachment'. But I believe it is not a good solution because I need source to be attached with jar. It helps while debugging, code browsing. If source is not attached then, your breakpoint stops there and you can't go in readable source.

BETTER SOLUTION NEEDED. Is there a launcher option??? which disables when app launched. or build options.??

Comment: Governa's solution is much better.

Comment: I also had to restart Eclipse before it cleaned up its cache (specifically, there a reference in .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.core/.org.eclipse.jdt.core.external.folders/.project that only went away after a restart)

Comment: @chrispy - You could probably accomplish the same thing by closing and opening the project(s) that were affected. (However, if there were a lot of projects, then restarting Eclipse would probably be simpler.)

Comment: There is no source attached in my case still every time I try to run the project eclipse show refreshing external folders. Can you please help? It take too long to do so.

Comment: No, this answer is definitely much better.

Answer (score 29):

Instead of attaching a source folder to the .jar file, you should zip the source folder and attach the zipped file to the .jar.

See this answer for more info https://stackoverflow.com/a/9699242/637754

Comment: This answer is obviously better than the accepted one, advising to remove the source attachment

Answer (score 9):

this helped me so you can try too:

Go to your **Workspace root/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.core/** and remove **.org.eclipse.jdt.core.external.folders** folder

it contains **.project** file with links to external folders which takes too long to refresh

Comment: dont have `org.eclipse.jdt.core.external.folders` in my given directory

Comment: it's ".org.eclipse.jdt.core.external.folders", with a leading "." (hidden folder)

Answer (score 1):

You can disable "Refresh on access" option in Window->Preferences->General->Workspace - it have no effect as I think, because even it's turned on you must manually refresh projects if you modify them outside of Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

If anything else fails (my case), install a fresh copy of Eclipse Juno 
Go to Help-Install Software, and add this repo:
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
Check all options and install.
For migration reasons I was trying to install Eclipse on MAC OS Yosemite, since Android Studio is now the official IDE, it is hard to find Eclipse setups with the ADT plugin included. I tried several versions of Eclipse, and JUNO did the work.