# Launching android application from eclipse On device very slow

Tags: android, eclipse, android-launcher

I don't why, but every time that i launching my application on real device is take several minutes .

Any body know why it's Occurs?

I run on Kepler (Eclipse)

**EDIT**

Maybe it's factor. My application it's build like that:

Main lib with android classes.

Android application that use Main Lib.

Maybe the runing is slow because this?

Comment: It depends on ur app, if there are too many works in background at start it will take time.Try to use different fast device.

Comment: if you can show some of your code, we can say where is the problem. Like memory problem etc etc.

Comment: I dont think that is attached to my application.it's occurs to all my co-workers. I think that is because the eclipse properties

Comment: is there any large size images or any music...... if this then it will take too much time

Comment: yes. the application it's with many images. it's no any way to pass this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem..

The workspace sit at cloud that use disk drive at my computer.

Answer (score 0):

You might be experiencing issue with “Refreshing external Folders”. If so the solution can be found here  [How to avoid "Refreshing external Folders" in Android development in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309203/how-to-avoid-refreshing-external-folders-in-android-development-in-eclipse)