# Impossible to create a new app with Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

With Eclipse, I can't succeed in creating a new Android app. After having clicked on "File"-"Android application project", I choose the options I need but, when I click on the "Finish" button, the application hangs... Currently, it is telling me "Refreshing external folders:(99%)" and this message appeared 5 minutes ago.

I have seen in other questions that the problem could be related to the ".android" folder, so I deleted it and restarted the SDK manager to recreate it. No improvement!

I have also tried several times to uninstall the SDK and Eclipse but with no result...

What can I do?

I use Eclipse Luna and my SDK is up to date.

Comment: i'm not going to fix your problem but i'm saying that android studio is far better than eclipse .you can move to it.

Comment: Have you tried this solution?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309203/how-to-avoid-refreshing-external-folders-in-android-development-in-eclipse

Comment: No. But to modify the project's build path, I must have a project first! If I violently close Eclipse while hung in the creation process, I get a project with empty source file, layout file and manifest file...

Comment: I have started to test Android Studio. I think I am about to head toward another development tool change, since it seems to works quickly and easily...